# Connecting to teradata using Grails

Tags: grails, teradata

I am completely new in Grails. We are trying to create a web application in which we are fetching data from teradata and displaying it to the user. 
Can we connect to teradata using Grails? How can this be implemented?
If yes then is this connection going to be asynchronous web service?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what type of teradata application you have but looking at the [public downloads](http://downloads.teradata.com/download) for teradata it appears there is the option of using a JDBC driver.

Using that JDBC driver your Grails application should be able to connect to the teradata application.